# Meaning of “We shall always place education side by side with instruction; the mind will not be cultivated at the expense of the heart.”

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this quote mean to you in terms of education:

> We shall always place education side by side with instruction; the mind will not be cultivated at the expense of the heart.

Written by the founder of the Congregation of Holy Cross, Blessed Basil Moreau

Comment: I would agree that "place education side by side with instruction" is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Consider that instruction is what the teacher does and education is something the student attains. Classic approaches to instruction are not always the most educational.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Moreau was French. This means that the sentence is almost certainly a translation.  Translations cannot always replicate the subtleties of the original language.

French is a Latinate language. Without going into details, "to educate" comes from the Latin "ex ducere" which means "to bring out" whereas "instruct" comes from "in struere" which means "to build in".

**My interpretation**

If you instruct someone, you put something into their mind, for example facts and rules. If you educate someone, you bring something out of them - you develop them, you reveal their true heart.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *instruction* has a specialized meaning relating to Christian *doctrine*. At any rate, there's no support or recognition of possible jargon. [To make Jesus Christ better known and better loved, through Education and Instruction](https://www.brothersofchristianinstruction.org/). And  [The church instructs in Christian doctrine](https://www.studylight.org/dictionaries/hbd/i/instruction.html). I suspect there is a secular/doctrinal distinction.

Comment: @Phil Sweet -  That sounds interesting. Perhaps you could expand it into an answer.

Comment: To what extent does the quoted dictum imply that each of the two processes works upon just one of the two aspects of personhood here conventionally metonymized as "mind" and "heart"? Such an implication would seem to me to be a falsehood, but in any case answering the question of what this statement means would seem to require considering how exclusive a one-to-one correlation is implied, and what that might imply in turn.